# Only want the first if several matches are returned

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL script that returns a number of records. This is the code:

```
select distinct eb.exerciseindex, eb.exercisestarttime, AVG(pb.playerbirthyear) as Birthavg, COUNT(pb.playerindex) as playersinexercise, pb.playersex from playerbase as pb
inner join exbase as ex on ex.explayerindex = pb.playerindex
inner join exercisebase as eb on eb.exerciseindex = ex.exexerciseindex
where exerciseallowanceindex='B26E10C5-53E1-413A-8A49-A7088D33E690'
and exercise_is_paying='true'
group by exercisestarttime, pb.playersex, eb.exerciseindex 
order by exerciseindex, playersinexercise desc
```

I have attached an image with the results.

Now, what I want is a kind of DISTINCT on the results. If you note, on some occasions several rows are returned for the same EXERCISEINDEX (see row 1 and 2 for example). But what I need is that only the FIRST row for this exerciseindex is returned (the one with the higher PLAYERCOUNT).

Any ideas how this can be done?

Regards,

Bob

[image: returned sql]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into a neat little so-called window function called [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Using this, you would do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY exerciseindex ORDER BY playersinexercise DESC) AS N
    FROM (
        -- your original query goes here - except for the ORDER BY clause --
    ) AS T1
) T2 WHERE T2.N = 1
-- put your ORDER BY clause here --
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use `ROW OVER` analytic function for this like below, then collect only those row for which `Row` value is 1.

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY exerciseindex ORDER BY exerciseindex) AS Row
```

For your case, it would be (You can use a CTE for that purpose)

```
WITH Query1 AS (
SELECT *,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY exerciseindex ORDER BY exerciseindex) AS Row
FROM 
(
select distinct eb.exerciseindex, 
eb.exercisestarttime, 
AVG(pb.playerbirthyear) as Birthavg, 
COUNT(pb.playerindex) as playersinexercise, 
pb.playersex from playerbase as pb
inner join exbase as ex on ex.explayerindex = pb.playerindex
inner join exercisebase as eb on eb.exerciseindex = ex.exexerciseindex
where exerciseallowanceindex = 'B26E10C5-53E1-413A-8A49-A7088D33E690'
and exercise_is_paying='true'
group by exercisestarttime, pb.playersex, eb.exerciseindex 
order by exerciseindex, playersinexercise desc
) tab
)
select * from Query1 where Row = 1;
```